# Invalid Bundle Structure - libSwiftRemoteMirror not permitted : When submit with App loader

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, xcode8, appstore-approval, application-loader

I know it's duplicate. I got problem only when I try to upload with application loader and When **I upload with Xcode Archive method then it is submitted successfully on AppStore**. So I don't understand the problem. I just want to know what is problem with AppLoader?